# Is there any service on AWS that can help me convert mp4 files to mp3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, transcoding, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm new to Amazon web services and I'm wondering if the platform offers any solution to convert media files to different formats ( mp4 to mp3) or do I have to use a lambda function with a third party library to achieve this.
Thank you !

Comment: Take a look at [Elastic Transcoder](https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/) - I'm not sure of your exact use case but it has a bunch of conversion capabilities.  Otherwise you can run `ffmpeg` in a Lambda to do something similar but, again, it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get up and running quickly with Elastic Transcoder. You will need to:

- create two s3 buckets, your 'inbox' and 'outbox'
- add a transcoder pipeline specifying which bucket is your in/out buckets, and you what file types you want to transcode from and two.
- you can set up a trigger so that every time something hits the in bucket, the process runs, or you can place something in the in bucket and use the sdk or cli to trigger a job.

Two things to note:

- When you fire a job, you have to pass in the name of the file that will be created. If the file already exists in the out bucket, an error will be thrown.
- As with all of aws' complete services, you get a little free up front, then it gets expensive. Once you get the hang of it, you can save some money rolling your own in lambda [like this](https://intoli.com/blog/transcoding-on-aws-lambda/)